# Change Column Type and Format

Tags: excel, vba, types

I have a spreedsheet with more than 200k rows and 85 columns. I need to change the column type to a specify format for each Column if the Column Name is found on another Sheet. The problem is, the code below is taking more than 25 min to finish.

aTemplate = The Sheet with I have the Column name and Types
aTemplate2 = The Sheet with my Data which I need to format each Column

Is it possible to improve this method? See the code Below.

```
     aTemplate = Worksheets("Format Parameters").Range("A2", Worksheets("Format Parameters").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    aTemplate2 = Worksheets("DADOS").Range("A1", Worksheets("DADOS").Cells(Rows.Count, "CI").End(xlUp))

    lCount2 = UBound(aTemplate2, 1)
    
    For cCount2 = LBound(aTemplate2, 2) To UBound(aTemplate2, 2)
         For lCount = LBound(aTemplate, 1) To UBound(aTemplate, 1)
            If aTemplate(lCount, 1) = aTemplate2(1, cCount2) Then  'Compare Column name
                For i = 2 To lCount2 'for each row 
                    Select Case aTemplate(lCount, 2)  ' Verify the type which I need to change the column
                        Case "Text"
                            With ActiveCell(i, cCount2)
                                .NumberFormat = "@"
                                .Value = .Value
                            End With
                        Case "Integer"
                            With ActiveCell(i, cCount2)
                                .NumberFormat = "0"
                                .Value = .Value
                            End With
                        Case "Date"
                            With ActiveCell(i, cCount2)
                                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                                .Value = .Value
                            End With
                        Case "Decimal"
                            With ActiveCell(i, cCount2)
                                .NumberFormat = "0.000"
                                .Value = .Value
                            End With
                        Case Else
                    End Select
                Next i
            Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I believe that the ActiveCell Method is why is taking so much to run this function.

Comment: The triple nested loops are what's causing the bulk of the slow runtime almost certainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should be exponentially faster.

- Loop over each column in the main table.
- Look up the column name (using `Match`) in the first column of the lookup table.
- Return the corresponding format type from the second column of the lookup table.
- Apply the corresponding number format to the entire column of the main table.

```
With Worksheets("Format Parameters")
    Dim aTemplate As Range
    Set aTemplate =  .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
End With

With Worksheets("DADOS")
    Dim aTemplate2 As Range
    Set aTemplate2 = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "CI").End(xlUp))
End With

With aTemplate2
    Dim col As Range
    For Each col In .Columns
        Dim matchRow
        matchRow = Application.Match(col.Cells(1).Value, aTemplate.Columns(1), 0)

        If Not IsError(matchRow) Then
            With col.Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
                Select Case aTemplate.Columns(2).Cells(matchRow).Value
                    Case "Text"
                       .NumberFormat = "@"
                       .Value = .Value
                    Case "Integer"
                       .NumberFormat = "0"
                       .Value = .Value
                    Case "Date"
                       .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                       .Value = .Value 
                    Case "Decimal"
                       .NumberFormat = "0.000"
                       .Value = .Value
                End Select
            End With
        End If
    Next
End With
```